# Is there a space leak in this Haskell implementation of LPath?

Tags: haskell, ocaml, ghc, space-leak

For fun I'm attempting to write an implementation of the naive longest path algorithm (for finding the length of the longest acyclic path in a cyclic graph). I started with a direct port of the imperative algorithm, which worked and performed fairly well.

```hs
data Route = Route {dest:: !Int32, cost:: !Int32}

type Node = [Route]

lPathImperative :: V.Vector Node -> Int32 -> UMV.IOVector Bool -> IO (Int32)
lPathImperative !nodes !nodeID !visited = do
  UMV.write visited (fromIntegral nodeID) True
  max <- newIORef 0
  Prelude.mapM_  (\ Route{dest, cost} -> do
         isVisited <- UMV.read visited (fromIntegral dest)
         case isVisited of
           True -> return ()
           False -> do
               dist <- fmap (+ cost) $ lPathImperative nodes dest visited
               maxVal <- readIORef max
               if dist > maxVal then writeIORef max dist else return ())
     (nodes V.! (fromIntegral nodeID))
  UMV.write visited (fromIntegral nodeID) False
  readIORef max
```

Where `visited` is an unboxed mutable vector of bools representing whether each node in the graph has currently been visited, all initialised to false, and nodes is a vector of nodes..

I then attempted to make it more functional, by having `max` as a value that is passed along in a fold, instead of as an IORef, as follows:

```hs
lPathFun :: V.Vector Node -> Int32 -> UMV.IOVector Bool -> IO (Int32)
lPathFun !nodes !nodeID !visited = do
  UMV.write visited (fromIntegral nodeID) True
  let max = CM.foldM acc (0::Int32) (nodes V.! (fromIntegral nodeID))
  UMV.write visited (fromIntegral nodeID) False
  max
    where
      acc :: Int32 -> Route -> IO (Int32)
      acc maxDist Route{dest,cost}  = do
          isVisited <- UMV.read visited (fromIntegral dest)
          case isVisited of
            True -> return maxDist
            False -> do
              dist <- fmap (+ cost) $ lPathFun nodes dest visited
              return $ if dist > maxDist then dist else maxDist
```

This version however fails to complete, running for minutes (the other took seconds for the same input) before dying with `out of memory (requested 1048576 bytes)`. I would be grateful if somebody could take a look over my code for `lPathFun` and see what I'm doing wrong. I've tried making everything in it strict, but that didn't help, and also tried making everything lazy, with no change. I even tried changing `type node` to `V.Vector route` and using strict `foldM'` on it instead, to no avail.

I suspect the problem is a space leak. This is because I tried translating `lPathFun` into OCaml and it worked fine (the fact that the OCaml version uses manual recursion shouldn't make a difference: my functional Haskell version initially used manual recursion too, but suffered the same problems as with using foldM):

```ml
type route = {dest: int; cost: int}
type node = route array

let rec lPathFun (nodes: node array) nodeID visited =
  visited.(nodeID) <- true;
  let rec loop i maxDist =
    if i < 0 then maxDist
    else
      let neighbour = nodes.(nodeID).(i) in
      if (not visited.(neighbour.dest))
      then
        let dist = neighbour.cost + lPathFun nodes neighbour.dest visited in
        let newMax = if dist > maxDist then dist else maxDist in
        loop (i-1) newMax
      else
        loop (i-1) maxDist in
  let (max: int) = loop (Array.length nodes.(nodeID) - 1) 0 in
  visited.(nodeID) <- false;
  max;;
```

The GHC version I'm using is 7.8.3.

Comment: You might find [this article](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/06/pinpointing-space-leaks-in-big-programs/) helpful for debugging space leaks.

Comment: Can you give us a full running program that we can run to help with the diagnosis?  A main function passing some example input to `lPathFun` should be sufficient.

Comment: I suspect there's a bigger problem with your algorithm.  Currently you are avoiding running the `max` computation until *after* you have written `False` into the `nodeID` position.  Don't you want `max <- CM.foldM ...; ...; return max` instead of `let max = CM.foldM ...; ...; max`?

Comment: user5402 beat me to it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `let max = ...` looks suspicious here:

```
lPathFun !nodes !nodeID !visited = do
  UMV.write visited (fromIntegral nodeID) True
  let max = CM.foldM acc (0::Int32) (nodes V.! (fromIntegral nodeID))
  UMV.write visited (fromIntegral nodeID) False
  max
```

Your code is equivalent to:

```
  UMV.write ... True
  UMV.write ... False
  CM.foldM acc ...
```

but I'm sure you want:

```
  UMV.write visited ... True
  max <- CM.foldM ...
  UMV.write visited ... False
  return max
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I don't understand do notation as well as I thought I did.